# strlen() is not working properly

Tags: php

i am not really good at this, this is my code. it seems like strlen() is not working, can someone help me figure what is wrong? thanks. it keeps on printing that password is too short even if i put 5 or more letters

```
<?php
if($username)
 {
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       $newpass =md5($_POST['newpass']);
       $confirmpass = md5($_POST['confirmpass']);

        if(strlen($newpass) < 5)
        {
          if($newpass == $confirmpass)
        {

  $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = '$newpass' WHERE        username = '$username'");
  session_destroy();
   ?> <script> alert ( "Your password has been changed!" );
  window.location='login.php'; </script>    <?php
         }

        else
         {
             ?> <script> alert ("New passwords don't match!" ); </script>   <?php
         }
     }
    else
    {
       echo "<font color='red'> * new password too short";
    }

 }
}

?>
```

Comment: Tell us please why do you think that `strlen` not working properly.

Comment: You are hashing your password before calling `strlen` on it, therefore the password's length is changed.

Comment: @u_mulder it keeps on printing the "new password is too short even if i already put 5 or more letters

Comment: I hope this isn't meant to go live or isn't live. Also why `session_destroy();`? There is no session definition.

Comment: md5 hashing generates a 32 character output. So yes, your password will always be bigger than 5 characters.

Comment: Just to make it clear: **don't use md5 for hashing passwords**. It's about as secure as not hashing them at all.

Comment: thanks guys/girls,  i felt stupid now, but hey, i fixed it, i already found the answer thank you all so much :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all - doing `md5` to a string will return a 32-character string.
That means that any password input by user will be hashed to a string of length 32.

This means that `if(strlen($newpass) < 5)` will never be true and you will always see a warning.

In this string you probably want `if(strlen($newpass) > 5)` - see, **greater**.
Then you password will be processed.

So, final code can be:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(strlen($_POST['newpass']) >= 5)
    {
        $newpass = md5($_POST['newpass']);
        $confirmpass = md5($_POST['confirmpass']);
        // do other stuff
    } else {
        // warn about short password
    }
}
```

Also take into consideration that `strlen` on `UTF-8` encoded strings **may** give you unexpected results.

And for passwords you **must** use better methods then `md5`. Look at `password_hash, password_verify`.

Comment: hey it worked! i felt stupid, but thank you very much! :) @u_mulder

Comment: Glad  it worked. There were some important comments made by others about not using md5 for password hashing. Hope you are taking this seriously.